# Getting List elements in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an ArrayList with elements for example:

```
var x = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

how can I store only the first 3 [1,2,3] elements in another list?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`take`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/Iterable/take.html) function:

```dart
var x = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

var y = x.take(3).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `take` function as `@Christopher Moore` said
or the `sublist` function

```
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

var usingTake = x.take(3).toList(); // 1,2,3
var usingSubList = x.sublist(0, 3); // 1,2,3
```

You can also use `sublist` to take any portion of the list.

For example: Getting the last 3 elements will be like:

```
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var usingSubList = x.sublist(x.length - 3, x.length);
```